# ${\bf Set}$ is the category of sheaves on the one-point topological space

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

It is well-known that ${\bf Set}$ is the category of sheaves on the one-point topological space, i.e. ${\bf Set} \simeq Sh(X,J_{\mathcal{O}(X)})$, with $X=\{x\}$.

Now, the open sets are $\mathcal{O}(X):=\{\emptyset,X\}$. Then $J(\emptyset)=\{ \emptyset,M_\emptyset\}$ (i.e. the empty sieve and the maximal one) and $J(X)=\{M_X\}$.

Now, using matching families, it may be easily shown that any presheaf is a sheaf (unless I did not do the correct computations). My question is: may I construct the equivalence associating with each presheaf $P$ the set $P(X)$?

Comment: You don't put Grothendieck topologies on sets – you put Grothendieck topologies on categories! The category you use when defining sheaves on a topological space is the category of open subsets. What are the open subsets of the one-point space? Hint: there's more than one.

Comment: I corrected the misprint. Well, there are two open sets, clearly. So, the corresponding topology should be given by respectively $J(\emptyset)=\{S_0\}$, where $S_0$ contains only the identity on $\emptyset$, and $J(X)=\{S_1,M_X\}$, where $S_1$ contains only the identity on $X$ and $M_X$ is the maximal sieve (there are the only two arrows with $X$ as codomain). So, I do not have the trivial topology, but $J_{\mathcal{O}(X)}$, right? In this case, how to show that ${\bf Set} \simeq Sh(X)=Sh(\mathcal{O}(X),J_{\mathcal{O}(X)})$?

Comment: That’s not correct. You should review the definitions. A sieve that contains the identity must be the maximal sieve, for example. Also, the empty sieve covers the empty set.

Comment: It is not true that every presheaf is a sheaf. A presheaf on the category of opens of a singleton involves two independently chosen sets with a function between them, so clearly the category of presheaves is not the same as the category of sets. Think about the empty sieve on the empty set more.

Comment: I have no clue. Please, can you help me?

Comment: From the sheaf axioms, derive that $F(\varnothing)$ must be a singleton if $F$ is a sheaf.